# How can I disable keyboard input on an html input of type number? What about in react or material-ui?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I have an `<input>` tag of `type="number"`, and I would like to disable keyboard input in order to force the user to change the value with the spinner (up and down arrows). I am consuming the input value on every change, so I want to do this so that I don't have to validate user input in real-time, which seems like the only alternative.

Outside of vanilla html and javascript, I would also like to know how to do this in [react](http://reactjs.org/) and [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/). If I have something like the following, how can I prevent keyboard input?

```js
  const [value, setValue] = useState(10);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <TextField
        name="name"
        type="number"
        label="label"
        inputProps={{
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
          step: 2,
        }}
        defaultValue={value}
        onChange={(event) => {
          setValue(Number(event.target.value));
        }}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems like a basic question, but I was surprised to not be able to find the answer anywhere, so I'm providing one here.

The key in both cases is to capture the [`onkeydown` event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp) and run its method [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

### Vanilla HTML and javascript

```html
  <input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="2" value="10"
    onkeydown="preventKeyboardInput(event)" />

  <script>
    function preventKeyboardInput(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  </script>
```

### React

```js
  <input
    type="number"
    min={0}
    max={100}
    defaultValue={10}
    step={2}
    onKeyDown={(event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
    }}
  />
```

### Material-UI

Material-UI's `<TextField>` is a wrapper around react's `<input>`, so all you need to do is pass `onKeyDown` down via `inputProps`, which you are already using to pass `min`, `max`, and `defaultValue`.

```js
  const [value, setValue] = useState(10);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <TextField
        name="name"
        type="number"
        label="label"
        inputProps={{
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
          step: 2,
          onKeyDown: (event) => {
             event.preventDefault();
          },
        }}
        defaultValue={value}
        onChange={(event) => {
          setValue(Number(event.target.value));
        }}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
```

---

UPDATE: I've discovered roundabout that this breaks input boxes on touch devices, or at the very least iOS and iPadOS, neither of which display or allow input from spinners, which is probably why it was downvoted in the first place. Caveat emptor for anyone wanting to use this method.

Comment: Problem with this approach is that you can't type anything in the input field anymore

Comment: @Acesif That was actually the whole point of the question. The title reads, "How can I *disable keyboard input*...". I agree that this probably isn't a good thing to do in practice (see the UPDATE at the end of the answer), but it answers the question as asked.